# How can i see my images directory contents using finder in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I saved some edited images in my own created directory under my app folder by using iPhone simulator at run time. Now i want to see my edited images in the mac finder. Do you know that how can i see my edited images in the finder which have been created at runtime by iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's located at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<OS_VERSION>/Applications/`

The folder is usually hidden, so use the "Go to Folder..." shortcut in Finder.

Comment: I am facing one more problem.

Comment: I am facing one more problem. I have a directory named as Album under my Supporting Files group. In this directory i have some images. In my image editing app i want to save my edited image in my album directory. I tried to save the image in my album directory by using the following code

Comment: NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *albumPath = [bundleRoot stringByAppendingString:@"/Album"];
NSString *savedImagePath = [bundleRoot stringByAppendingPathComponent:    @"newImage11.jpeg"    ];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.image.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[drawImage.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *editedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData  *editedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(editedImage, 1.0); UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
[editedImageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

Comment: Here drawImage is the IBOutlet of UIImageView which holds the image.This code saved a file newImage11.jpeg in my album directory which has a size also. but when i retrieve the image from album directory it gives me a blank image. I used the following code to retrieve the image

Comment: NSString *img = [onlyJPGs objectAtIndex:currentIndex+numberToAdd];
    
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
    
    imageButton.tag = img;
    [imageButton setImage:tempImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imageButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(goToEdit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    currentIndex+=numberToAdd;

Comment: onlyJPGs is an array which holdes the name of all images contained in the Album directory.  I am sure that my app is saving the image in Album directory because when i list the contents of Album directory in ImageEditing.app by using terminal it shows me the newImage11.jpeg file. Any kind of help would be appreciable.

Comment: It's not the same question. You should accept the answer for your original question and post a new one for a new question.